# Where is dconf in ubuntu-12.04 desktop-32 bit

Tags: permissions, security, dconf, restricted-access

I am not able to find dconf in ubuntu-12.04 desktop-32 bit?

Comment: Where were you expecting to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Also, if dconf is present in your current installation (12.04), then open up a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `dconf` and it should open before your eyes.

Answer (score 0):

If is not present in your system, install it from here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools/.